# Build array from another array if some key are identical using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data. Some of the key in the array are same. I would like to create a new array based on the key and add the other data.

This is my array

```
 var myObjOne = [
        {
        "name":"John",
        "id":1,
        "car":"maruti"
       },
       {
        "name":"John",
        "id":2,
        "car":"wolks"
       },
       {
        "name":"John",
        "id":3,
        "car":"bmw"
       },        
      {
        "name":"Peter",       
        "id":4, 
        "car":"alto"                           
      },
      {
        "name":"Peter",       
        "id":5, 
        "car":"swift"                           
      }
    ];
```

I would like to convert the array in to the below format.

```
var myObj = [
          {
          "name":"John",
          "items": [
              { "id":1, "car":"maruti" },  
              { "id":2, "car":"wolks" },
              { "id":3, "car":"bmw" }            
          ]},
          {
            "name":"Peter",
          "items": [
              { "id":4, "car":"alto" },  
              { "id":5, "car":"swift" },                          
          ]
       }
      ];
```

I am working on a node environment.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already. We'll happily help you work out the kinks with your solutions, but SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.reduce is at rescue.This method accepts an `accumulator` and `current` 
item. Check in the accumulator if there exist an object where the value of name property is John or Peter

```js
var myObjOne = [{
    "name": "John",
    "id": 1,
    "car": "maruti"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": 2,
    "car": "wolks"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": 3,
    "car": "bmw"
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "id": 4,
    "car": "alto"
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "id": 5,
    "car": "swift"
  }
];

var newObj = myObjOne.reduce(function(acc, curr, currIndex) {
  // using findIndex to check if there exist an object
  // where the value of the name property is John, Peter
  // if it exist it will return the index else it will return -1
  let ifNameExist = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.name === curr.name;
  })
  // if -1 then create a object with name and item property and push
  // it to the accumulator
  if (ifNameExist === -1) {
    let nameObj = {};
    nameObj.name = curr.name;  
    nameObj.items = [];
    nameObj.items.push({
      id: curr.id,
      car: curr.car
    })
    acc.push(nameObj)
  } else {
    // if such an object already exist then just update the item array
    acc[ifNameExist].items.push({
      id: curr.id,
      car: curr.car
    })

  }


  return acc;

}, []);
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an object using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) first which maps name with items, and then create the final array by looping over the intermediate map using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
var source = [{"name":"John","id":1,"car":"maruti"},{"name":"John","id":2,"car":"wolks"},{"name":"John","id":3,"car":"bmw"},{"name":"Peter","id":4,"cars":"alto"},{"name":"Peter","id":5,"cars":"swift"}];

const map = source.reduce((acc, {name, ...obj}) => {
  if (!acc[name]) {
    acc[name] = [];
  }
  
  acc[name].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = [];

for (let[name, items] of Object.entries(map)) {
  result.push({name, items});
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.reduce` to group by name, and use `.find` inside the reducer to find if the matching `name` has already been added:

```js
const input=[{"name":"John","id":1,"car":"maruti"},{"name":"John","id":2,"car":"wolks"},{"name":"John","id":3,"car":"bmw"},{"name":"Peter","id":4,"cars":"alto"},{"name":"Peter","id":5,"cars":"swift"}]
const output = input.reduce((a, { name, ...item }) => {
  const foundNameObj = a.find(nameObj => nameObj.name === name);
  if (foundNameObj) foundNameObj.items.push(item);
  else a.push({ name, items: [item] });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```